# AKS cluster pod is being polled by unknown pod IP

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

After setting up a Kubernetes service running an FTP application with port mapping 21 inside AKS, I noticed that port 21 is being probed by some kind of process. The following is being logged from within my FTP application:

```
[I 2019-12-06 23:38:56] 10.244.0.1:56287-[] FTP session closed (disconnect).
[I 2019-12-06 23:38:56] 10.244.0.1:56330-[] FTP session opened (connect)
[I 2019-12-06 23:39:02] 10.244.0.1:56330-[] FTP session closed (disconnect).
[I 2019-12-06 23:39:02] 10.244.0.1:56376-[] FTP session opened (connect)
```

- The VM this pod is on has IP range **10.244.0.0/24**
- There is no Container Insights or anything else configured
- I don't believe this is Readiness or Liveness probes, as I have overridden those - but it does look a lot like some kind of generic TCP probe on whatever port is being configured in the port mapping?
- The full dump of all pods gives

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE                       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   coredns-866fc6b6c8-5cgll                1/1     Running   0          86m     10.244.0.7    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-866fc6b6c8-nrbk2                1/1     Running   0          93m     10.244.0.4    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-autoscaler-5d5695b54f-82jkb     1/1     Running   0          92m     10.244.0.2    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-sk59f                        1/1     Running   0          81m     10.240.0.4    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-6f697bd9f5-s7kgz   1/1     Running   0          92m     10.244.0.5    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system   metrics-server-566bd9b4f7-gqnw9         1/1     Running   1          93m     10.244.0.3    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
kube-system   tunnelfront-855c64f898-xhk6m            1/1     Running   0          92m     10.244.0.6    aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
test          test-b8487b946-z6tlb                 1/1     Running   0          9m24s   10.244.0.13   aks-agentpool-40501316-0   <none>           <none>
```

I must be missing something obvious here. What is constantly polling my application every 6 seconds? On a node with IP range 10.244.0.0/24, what is the thing that is being created at 10.244.0.1?

Comment: Any chance that image declares a `HEALTHCHECK`?

Comment: No, since I have overriden both live and readiness checks, unless you mean something else?

Comment: When talking about Readiness or Liveness probes you said they where overridden. What does override mean? You just changed the probe settings? You just not included them? Can you be more specific in this matter? 
What's exactly the FTP solution that you're using? How it was implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a service of type `LoadBalancer` mapped to this pod - this would be the Azure Load Balancer probes doing the health check to determine if the service is alive.

Comment: Under the Kubernetes load balancer, then Health Probes, I already moved these probes from 5 seconds to 50 seconds. The application logging still shows the port being hit every 6 seconds. Is this normal behaviour?